# Отношения Laravel, как правильно получить

Tags: laravel

Модель филиала

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Модель оплат

```
public function pays(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product_pay::class);
}
```

Суть в том что у каждого филиала есть продукты, а у продуктов есть оплаты.В таблице все связи прописаны.

`Branch::find(1)->products` (корректно получаю список продуктов в филиале с ид 2 и 3)

`Product::find(2)->pays` (корректно получаю список оплат в продукте)

Но если пытаюсь получить сразу `Branch::find(1)->products->pays` то выдает ошибку

```
Exception with message 'Property [pays] does not exist on this collection instance.'
```

Что я не так делаю? Можно ли сразу получить коллекцию у филиала продуктов а в них оплаты ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты правильно пишешь, что `Branch::find(1)->products` возвращает "**список** продуктов". Получить "список оплат в продукте" можно у продукта, а не у "списка продуктов".

Можно обратиться к первому элементу коллекции и у него взять "список продуктов".

```
Branch::find(1)->products[0]->pays
```

Если же "список оплат" должен относится именно к "списку продуктов" (а не к отдельному продукту), то надо переделать модели. Должна быть отдельная сущность "список продуктов" к которой привязаны продукты и у которой есть "список оплат".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте еще такой вариант

```
Branch::with('pays')->whereIn('id', [1])->get();
```

Comment: Это я получу у филиала один продукт и его оплату, а если у филиала продуктов несколько, а у продуктов несколько оплат ?